# How to replace the Timedelta Pandas function with a pure PySpark function?

Tags: pandas, datetime, pyspark, date-range

I am developing a small script in PySpark that generates a date sequence (36 months before today's date) and (while applying a truncate to be the first day of the month). Overall I succeeded this task however

But with the help of the Pandas package Timedelta to calculate the time delta .

Is there a way to replace this Timedelta from Pandas with a pure PySpark function ?

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_trunc

today = datetime.today()
data = [((date(today.year, today.month, 1) - pd.Timedelta(36,'M')),date(today.year, today.month, 1))] # I want to replace this Pandas function
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["minDate", "maxDate"])

+----------+----------+
|   minDate|   maxDate|
+----------+----------+
|2016-10-01|2019-10-01|
+----------+----------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn("monthsDiff", f.months_between("maxDate", "minDate"))\
    .withColumn("repeat", f.expr("split(repeat(',', monthsDiff), ',')"))\
    .select("*", f.posexplode("repeat").alias("date", "val"))\ #
    .withColumn("date", f.expr("add_months(minDate, date)"))\
    .select('date')\
    .show(n=50)

+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2016-10-01|
|2016-11-01|
|2016-12-01|
|2017-01-01|
|2017-02-01|
|2017-03-01|
 etc...
+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pyspark inbuilt `trunc` function.

pyspark.sql.functions.trunc(date, format)
Returns date truncated to the unit specified by the format.

```
Parameters:
format – ‘year’, ‘YYYY’, ‘yy’ or ‘month’, ‘mon’, ‘mm’
```

Imagine I have a below dataframe.

```
list = [(1,),]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list, ['id'])

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df=df.withColumn("start_date" ,f.add_months(f.trunc(f.current_date(),"month") ,-36))
df=df.withColumn("max_date" ,f.trunc(f.current_date(),"month"))

>>> df.show()
+---+----------+----------+
| id|start_date|  max_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2016-10-01|2019-10-01|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Here's a link with more details on Spark date functions.

[Pyspark date Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for these answers, I'm going to refactor my code and post it here.